# Issues with WebRTC based application

Tags: webrtc, kurento, simplewebrtc

I have developed a `WebRTC` based application along with `Kurento-Media-Server`.

Problems with this application is:

1. It works but only on open network (i.e. if run on a network without firewall).
2. When in firewall it runs sometimes (once out of 10 attempts).

I have tried several things with the firewall, I have disabled all kind of incoming/outgoing traffic. I have created a port-forwarding for my application as well as Kurento-media server.

I am not sure how much useful this information might be but I am deploying my
application on the same physical box along with `Kurento-Media-Server`. I have configured google's STUN server on my client.js, I have also configured same STUN servers on kurento using code. I haven't configured TURN server.

Just confirming this, signaling server can be behind firewall along with rest of the application, correct?

I am not sure what to look for now, any help in this area would be great.

**EDIT-1**
From this [link](https://www.netscan.co) I learned that my current network on which my isn't working it has issues with plain websocket connection, it doesn't allow it, it only allows secure Websocket connections.

**EDIT-2**

Image of netscan:
[image: Scan Report]

In my phone network where my app works fine I see all greens in Websocket's "plain" column.

**EDIT-3** **Solved**
Finally found the problem, We were using a router for testing and development and I found that the router had issues, I used LAN cable on the same router and everything worked fine. Calls from application were working just fine. Firewall related details help in configuring the firewall later on.

Comment: Yes, you *might* need TURN servers, yes, the signalling server can be behind a firewall if the clients can contact it anyway in some way (that is pretty straight forward and testable).

Comment: I mean what issue I  could be facing here ?? I have tried all options, including TURN but TURN setup was failing and I had priorities to deliver hence I skip it. Should I focus on TURN now ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem description it seems all the UDP traffic is not open in your firewall. WebRTC media run on UDP ports.As you mentioned it works one out of 10 times whch means only few UDP ports are open in your firewall.You are lucky when traffic comes via tose ports.You can open  port-range in your firewall and configure the same in kurento-media-server config.Your job should be done.

Even if you configure TURN server you need to open certain ports for outgoing and incoming UDP traffic.For TURN server default port is 3478 or 8443 for sending data towards it but for incoming traffic you need to configure port-range on your TURN server and open those ports in your firewall. Always remember TURN server is assured way to connect but it's always costly.

Comment: Thanks for replying I did opened all UDP ports outgoing and incoming in my firewall and tried that, please see the edit in my question it is my new finding I just found it, let me know if there is a way to do so.

Comment: Buddy please share/attach your network report with Netscan. In your app issue could be either in media or signaling. Media issues depend on UDP settings as already explained.For signaling either enhance application for secure websocket or open non-secure websocket port ( default TCP port 80 ) in your firewall.

Comment: TCP Port 80 is generally used for which in your report is not open.Kindly try opening it and test.

Comment: One more question, I need to enable port 80 only for machine on which I am deploying my application, right ?

Comment: On machine and in ur firewall too...same is true for all UDP ports if required

Comment: ok  I tried but it is still not working, some how I found that 80 port is still not open, weird thing is I see two different result for netscan.co for same network, i.e. my mobile network is also showing the Websocket connectivity test same as in the image, which was all green few hours back.

Comment: Can you help me with websockets? I think my websocket gets  closed while on the firewall, I don't receive remote SDP on the other client, I think websocket gets closed, do you have any idea on such events related to websocket?

Comment: Sure i can but once its working with open n/w and not working in ur n/w which means issue is there with opening port 80, it shouldn't be anything related to code.

Comment: ok, first of all sorry, It was stupid wifi router issue, it wasn't working and almost 80% of the packets were lost, I connected it with LAN and put it behind firewall it worked :) :) :) , I found your information very useful in configuring firewall, now it is working fine. :) :) :) thanks :) :) :) :)

Comment: Thanks , Glad to hear that.

Comment: Would suggest to please upvote the relevant comments or answer so that others facing similar issues will get benefited as yours else SO will delete comments or demote answers  over a period of time